# Will the gradle file be put into when build an aar?

Tags: android, sdk, aar

I want to know what's the significance of gradle file in an aar. I just don't know how it work.Even I wonder whether it exsits in an aar or not. I'm confused how to get versionName in an aar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gradle files are not embedded into your aar. There are files used at compilation time and not at runtime.

> I'm confused how to get versionName in an aar.

What is your usecase ? What do you exactly want to do ?

Comment: I want to build an aar which need to obtain versionName uploading to server. And now, I know gradle file won't be built in aar. So I have to create a static class file to storage versionName. All confuses me is that I do really know nothing about the significance of gradle file when build an aar.

Comment: Are you talking about the `versionName' set in the gradle file ? If so, you must have a static class which retrieve it for you

Comment: That's what I did.